# Plugin: List category posts - How to show the caption under thumbnail

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I've been trying to get the caption to show under the thumbnail with css but to no avail. It keeps appearing on top.

css:

```
.lcp_catlist {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

.lcp_catlist li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.project-title {
}

.project-thumb {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

the shortcode:

```
[catlist id=3 numberposts=20 orderby=title order=asc title_tag=div title_class=project-title thumbnail=yes thumbnail_class=project-thumb thumbnail_size=thumbnail ]
```

From what i've search so far, the thumbnail need to be in a div for the float css to work. however, the plugin didn't give the option of using thumnail_tag option. is there a workaround to get the thumbnail to be in a div?

I'm not sure if this will help, but this is the html template for each post:

```
<ul>
<li>
<div class="project-title">POST TITLE</div>
<div class="project-thumb">My THUMBNAIL</div>
</li>
</ul>`
```

the problem is that the div for the image is at the bottom while div for the title is on top.

even though i played around with the settings for css, it seem to stay in that position. however, i cannot switch their places as that is in the core of the plugin.

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 2):

after a whole night of googling and test runs, I've resolved the matter by using List Category Posts' template. all I did was create another template (from the one provided by plugin) in a folder inside my theme's directory. Then i go in and edit the code by placing the show thumnail codes on top of the title codes, and Viola!, works like a charm.

thanks Sol for attempting for help me. I really appreciated that. ^^

Answer (score 1):

please either post the URL or look at page source and post the actual html code so that we can see the markup

Comment: it's on my localhost, so i can't really display it.

but here's a screenshot: http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/7974/23615186.jpg

and here's my css for it: http://pastebin.com/A9fF3AFw

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but this is the html template for each post:

`<ul>
<li>
<div class="project-title"><a href="my_link">Eniro Cinderella</a></div>
<div class="project-thumb"><a href="my_link"><img width="150" height="120" src="my-image.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image"></a></div>
</li>
</ul>`
the problem is that the div for the image is at the bottom while div for the title is on top.

even though i played around with the settings for css, it seem to stay in that position. however, i cannot switch their places as that is in the core of the plugin.

Comment: I didn't see any wp-caption reference in your exampl, so it's hard to troubleshoot without actually seeing the code. However, as a suggestion, why not create a simple gallery in WP page, then use firebug to look at the code and copy that?

Comment: Glad you got it solved and thanks for the vote up!